# right click context menu jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, contextmenu

Does anybody have any code for a jquery context menu? Just need a div popup at pointer position when right mouse button pressed.

Comment: Have you done a Google Search? There are many many scripts that point this out.

Comment: I found a very simple script that can do this (from another Stackoverflow question): http://stackoverflow.com/a/4502207/975097

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I found:

[Right Click Context Menu Using Jquery and asp.net - Code Project Article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/jQueryListViewWithContext.aspx)

[Plugins tagged Right Click Menu on Jquery website](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/right-click-menu/)

Interestingly, the [dogo library](http://dojotoolkit.org/) has a [standard set of UI widgets](http://dojotoolkit.org/widgets), and the [context menu is part of that standard UI set.](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/Menu.html) (The dojo library is nice and pretty with a standard look)

Dojo is a **separate javascript library** just *like* JQuery. Not sure how completely compatible dojo is *with* jquery, but there are ways to get them both working together if you want to.

Lord [Google](http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+drop+down+menu&qscrl=1#sclient=psy&hl=en&qscrl=1&source=hp&q=jquery+right+click+menu&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&psj=1&fp=9fa43f2022044924) gave me most of the answers ;)

---

Similar SO questions that might be helpful:
[jQuery Right-Click Context Menu Help!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996204/jquery-right-click-context-menu-help)
[jquery context menu plugin - Where is the right click event type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642358/jquery-context-menu-plugin-where-is-the-right-click-event-type)
[JavaScript: Capturing right click and disabling menu only within certain element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973321/javascript-capturing-right-click-and-disabling-menu-only-within-certain-element)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a plugin: 
[jQuery Context Menu](http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/)

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be achieved by using the event listener in jQuery, here is a clean and fast way of doing it:

```js
//Now add the jQuery
$(document).ready(function() { //Just starting up here
  var menu = $('.menu');//get the menu
  $(document).on('contextmenu', function(e) {//What this does is simply; if right-click, run function(contains an event)
    e.preventDefault();//Prevent the default action: the normal right-click-menu to show
    menu.css({
      display: 'block',//show the menu
      top: e.pageY,//make the menu be where you click (y)
      left: e.pageX//make the menu be where you click (x)
    });
  });
  $(document).click(function() { //When you left-click
    menu.css({ display: 'none' });//Hide the menu
  });
});
```

```css
/* just some css to display it */
.menu {
  background: #fff;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;//this is important
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery CDN --><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Add some HTML for the menu -->
<div class="menu">
  <p>Option 1</p>
  <p>Option 2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another plugin you can use is one developed by me called [Audero Context Menu](https://github.com/AurelioDeRosa/Audero-Context-Menu).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Right Click</title>

    <link href="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.ui.position.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <span class="context-menu-one" style="border:solid 1px black; padding:5px;">Right Click Me</span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        $(function() {
        $.contextMenu({
            selector: '.context-menu-one', 
            callback: function(key, options) {
                var m = "clicked: " + key;
                window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
            },
            items: {
                "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
                "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
               copy: {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
                "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
                "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
                "sep1": "---------",
                "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: function(){
                    return 'context-menu-icon context-menu-icon-quit';
                }}
            }
        });

        $('.context-menu-one').on('click', function(e){
            console.log('clicked', this);
        })    
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: code-only answers aren't answers IMO - add explanation so the OP and future readers can learn from it.